# How do you get each timer count value? dart flutter

Tags: flutter, timer, flutter-getx

```
void main() {
  final newTi = Get.put(NewTimer());
  ...
    ...
      ...: Obx((){
        return Text('${newTi.count}');
        // I'm trying to set a new timer and watch each of them. 
        // It's just 10. What should I do?
      }),
}
//
//
class NewTimer extends GetxController {
  RxInt count = 10.obs;
}
//
//
class TimerFunc extends GetxController {
  void timeRun() {
    NewTimer newTime = new NewTimer();
    Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 1), (t) {
      if (t.tick == 10) {
        t.cancel();
      } else {
        newTime.count--;
      }
    });
  }
}
```

I'm trying to set a new timer and watch each of them.
It's just 10. What should I do?

.........................................

Answer (score 0):

getter? setter? in Dart.

```
class NewTimer {
  double _count;

  NewTimer(this._count);

  double get count => _count;
  set count(double c) => _count = c;
}

void main() {
  print(NewTimer(2.0).count);
  print(NewTimer(3.0).count++);
}
```